# Why My Javascript random selector not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight

I want some help on this problem. I'm trying to get my JavaScript to highlight random picks that I enter in but its not working.

I keep getting a error message when I inspect my JS code on the webpage saying

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
    at highlightTag (script.js:52:9)
    at script.js:38:9"
```

Here's the all the code below:

```js
const tagsEl = document.getElementById('tags')
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

textarea.focus()

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  createTags(e.target.value)

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.value = ''
    }, 10)

    randomSelect()
  }
})

function createTags(input) {
  const tags = input.split(',').filter(tag => tag.trim() !==
    '').map(tag => tag.trim())

  tagsEl.innerHTML = ''

  tags.forEach(tag => {
    const tagEl = document.createElement('span')
    tagEl.classList.add('tag')
    tagEl.innerText = tag
    tagsEl.appendChild(tagEl)
  })
}

function randomSelect() {
  const times = 30

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const randomTag = pickRandomTag()

    highlightTag(randomTag)

    setTimeout(() => {
      unHighlightTag(randomTag)
    }, 100)
  }, 100);
}

function pickRandomTag() {
  const tags = document.querySelectorAll('.tag')
  return tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)]
}

function highlightTag(tag) {
  tag.classList.add('hightlight')
}

function unHighlightTag(tag) {
  tag.classList.remove('hightlight')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2b88f0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tag {
  background-color: #f0932b;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag.highlight {
  background-color: #273c75;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap&ext=.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h3>Enter all of the choices divided by a comma (','). <br> Press Enter when you are done</h3>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter choices here..." id="textarea"></textarea>
  <div id="tags">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please isolate your problem in a minimal example if possible? There's a lot going on here

Comment: Could you explain what the code is supposed to do vs what it is doing wrong right now?  We don't know that the content of `script.js` looks like so perhaps there is a conflicting statement there?

Comment: You keep creating a new interval each time you hit enter.

Comment: @blurfus It is the script that is there. Made more sense when it was not in a snipplet....

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you keep creating intervals. So you have an instance where you remove the element and the random code is trying to select them. It finds nothing and you have your problem. You need to cancel the intervals when you alter the tags and you should look to see if an element exists before you try to reference it if you are going to use innerHTML to make new tags.

```js
const tagsEl = document.getElementById('tags')
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

textarea.focus()

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  createTags(e.target.value)

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.value = ''
    }, 10)

    randomSelect()
  }
})

function createTags(input) {
  const tags = input.split(',').filter(tag => tag.trim() !==
    '').map(tag => tag.trim())

  tagsEl.innerHTML = ''

  tags.forEach(tag => {
    const tagEl = document.createElement('span')
    tagEl.classList.add('tag')
    tagEl.innerText = tag
    tagsEl.appendChild(tagEl)
  })
}

let selectInterval = null;
function randomSelect() {
  const times = 30
  
  // Is there an interval running? cancel it
  if (selectInterval) window.clearInterval(selectInterval);

  selectInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const randomTag = pickRandomTag()
    
    // Do we have something to toggle? If no, exit
    if (!randomTag) return;

    highlightTag(randomTag)

    setTimeout(() => {
      unHighlightTag(randomTag)
    }, 1000)
  }, 1000);
}

function pickRandomTag() {
  const tags = document.querySelectorAll('.tag')
  return tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)]
}

function highlightTag(tag) {
  tag?.classList?.add('hightlight')
}

function unHighlightTag(tag) {
  tag?.classList?.remove('hightlight')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2b88f0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tag {
  background-color: #f0932b;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag.hightlight {
  background-color: #273c75;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap&ext=.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h3>Enter all of the choices divided by a comma (','). <br> Press Enter when you are done</h3>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter choices here..." id="textarea"></textarea>
  <div id="tags">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: . this does not work. It should be a simple fix because I'm following a tutorial

Comment: The code is running fine right here so unsure how it does not fix it. What does not work?

Comment: FYI: Just because you are following a tutorial does not mean the tutorial is correct. Plenty of bad tutorials out there.